# clicking on a asp.net application link in outlook opens with same session id

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, session, outlook, sessionid

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932474

You open an ASP.NET-connected application in Internet Explorer. The application sends a Microsoft Outlook e-mail message that contains a hyperlink. In this scenario, you assume that the application will obtain a new session when you click the hyperlink in Outlook. However, Outlook uses the same session as the ASP.NET-connected application uses. This behavior occurs because the new page that is opened in Internet Explorer uses the existing Internet Explorer process instead of creating a new process. This behavior is by design because using an existing process saves resources and time.

To maintain the system state in this scenario, you can use a query string to store the state of the application. For more information about how to store a state in an active server pages application, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:

--

Does any one ever came across this kind of requirement? We need to achieve the exact same behavior as stated here - but the new window opened from outlook must have different session.

Any clues?

Scenario:
1. ASP.NET application opened in IE 6.0 - so it has a session
2. Click the link in OUTLOOK that goes to same application - opens in a new window or existing window.

1 and 2 have same sessions. Pathetic. I need point 2 to be opened in a new window with new session.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior will occur with every web-browser, not just with IE. The ASP.Net Session-ID is stored in a cookie that is used across all windows/tabs of the browser instance.

If your users *really* need to run different sessions at a time you could keep the data of multiple sessions within one session. To know which "sub-session" within the real session you are running you would need to keep some identifier in the querystring of every link though...